# Getting Error While Inserting JSON data to DynamoDB using Python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

```
    HI,

    I am trying to put the json data into AWS dynamodb table using AWS Lambda , however i am getting an error like below. My json file is uploaded to S3 bucket.

    Parameter validation failed:
    Invalid type for parameter Item, value:
    {
        "IPList": [
            "10.1.0.36",
            "10.1.0.27"
        ],
        "TimeStamp": "2020-04-22 11:43:13",
        "IPCount": 2,
        "LoadBalancerName": "internal-ALB-1447121364.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com"
    }
    , type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>: ParamValidationError

Below i my python script:-

    import boto3
    import json
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
        json_file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
        json_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket,Key=json_file_name)
        jsonFileReader = json_object['Body'].read()
        jsonDict = json.loads(jsonFileReader)
        table = dynamodb.Table('test')
        table.put_item(Item=jsonDict)

        return 'Hello'
```

Below is my json content

"{\"IPList\": [\"10.1.0.36\", \"10.1.0.27\"], \"TimeStamp\": \"2020-04-22 11:43:13\", 
\"IPCount\": 2, \"LoadBalancerName\": \"internal-ALB-1447121364.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com\"}"

Can someone help me, how can insert data to dynamodb.

Answer (score 0):

`json.loads(jsonFileReader)` returns `string`, but `table.put_item()` expects `dict`. Use `json.load()` instead.